# Basic custom function in R does not define the internal objects

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a function to automatize some basic computations. However it seems to not define the final `mat` object, even if the code embedded into the function perfectly works when put outside it.. clearly I am doing some basic error, but I cannot figure out what's wrong.

The code is:

```
my_f = function(covs, B, k) { 

  ### empty matrix

  coeff <- paste("b_", covs, sep="")
  se <- paste("se_", covs, sep="")
  mat <- matrix(nrow=B, ncol=2+2*k, dimnames=list(c(), c("sim","N",coeff,se)))
  mat[,"sim"] <- seq(1:B) 

} 

 my_f(covs=list("x1", "x2"), B=50, k=2)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In what way does it not work? What output are you expecting as opposed to what it is giving you?

Comment: @joran: It's true that the last line will sabotage the function but it will return exactly `seq(1:B)` because that is what the `[<-` will return.

Comment: @Dwin, Yes, but it will appear not to return that  unless you assign `my_f(...)` to something. Compare `my_f(covs=list("x1", "x2"), B=50, k=2)`, to `x <- my_f(covs=list("x1", "x2"), B=50, k=2);x`

Comment: Given your comment to the answer below, do you want to assign `mat` to the parent (global or otherwise) environment?

Comment: My memory was that seq(1:B) would not be the same as 1:B but my testing makes me question that memory.

Comment: @DWin: You're thinking of the fact that `seq(2:B)` is not the same as `2:B` (or any vector not of the form `1:X` where `X > 0`)- `seq` given one argument uses the *length* of the vector and then returns a vector with 1 to that length. Thus, since `1:B` is of length `B`, `seq(1:B)` returns `1:B`

Comment: Yes. Even more confusing is that `seq(50:1)` returns `1:50`.

Comment: @joran: If you delete and substitute something else, I'll delete mine (and this one as well) assuming it is accurate. The invisibility thing didn't seem to make a difference on what was returned, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's not clear what you want it to return, I think you forgot the line `return(mat)` at the end of the function.

As `myf` is currently defined, it will return only the last thing evaluated, `m[, "sim"]`, which is a vector (thus forgetting the rest of the matrix).

You'll also have to assign the result of `my_f` to a variable (which can be, but *does not have to be*, also named `mat`).

```
mat <- my_f(covs=list("x1", "x2"), B=50, k=2)
```

Comment: thanks! Can you explain how to define the `mat` object without having to show it on the R console? I would like to call it later

Comment: When `mat` is defined within the function, it exists only within that function's *scope*. That means that the moment the function finishes, `mat` is gone- *unless* it returns `mat` and the return value from the function is assigned to a new variable (which can also be called `mat`)

Comment: Use `invisible(mat)` instead of `return(mat)` if you don't want to see it in the console.

Comment: And assign the result of the function call to something. (That would have the effect of also not printing the value.)

Comment: Thanks to all of you, you made my life a lot easier! :)